# Keycloak18 index page "Resource not found"

Tags: keycloak

I would really appreciate some help with the current issue I am experiencing.

Context:
I have been upgrading my instance of keycloak from 16.x to 18.x.
After many hours of research, I have been defeated by this one issue.

Issue:
When I go to the site URL for this example `https://thing.com/` I am greeted with the following "Resource not found", instead of the keycloak welcome page.
In my chrome network monitoring it will show the following:

[Error with network monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kR3L.png)

Infra:
Keycloak lives on its machine. The URL reaches keycloak through a Caddy Service as a reverse proxy.

Relative scripts:
Docker-compose

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: "-XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=\"org.jboss.byteman\" -Djava.awt.headless=true"

      KC_HOSTNAME_PORT: 8080
      KC_HOSTNAME: ${KC_HOME}
      KC_PROXY: edge
      KC_DB_URL: 'jdbc:postgresql://${KEYCLOAK_DB_ADDR}/${KEYCLOAK_DB_DATABASE}?sslmode=require'
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_USERNAME: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_USER}
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_DB_PASSWORD}
      KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH: /auth
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: 'false'

    command: start --auto-build
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
    volumes:
      - backup:/var/backup
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -I http://127.0.0.1:8080/

volumes:
  backup:
```

NOTE: If I remove this `KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH: /auth` it will behave as intended. However, I would prefer I do not remove this aspect of the service as it is tied to that relative path for a lot of the services using keycloak.

I can replicate this with a local docker image built using the same environment variables.

Does anyone perhaps know some secret ninja moves I could do to get it to direct to the welcome page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatic redirect from `/` to `KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH` is not supported in Keycloak 18 (see https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10274).

You have to add the redirect in the reverse proxy, in Caddy there is [redir](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/redir).

Comment: Ah perfect thank you, I actually just went for this option shortly before your post.
Thank you :)